# Keep enter and tabs keys (spaces) in a reply message

Tags: php, mysql, post, string-formatting

im creating and message system, in the final steps im coding the reply then send the reply.
I have no problem filling in the text of the original message into the body of the reply, but when the reply is sent, the new spaces and tabs for the message history are gone, so the are all together after each other.  In DB the type is  `text`.

**Original message:**

`Test 1`

**Reply is like this:**

`Reply test 1 ----------------------------- The 2014-01-17 02:45:55, Mikey said : Test 1`

**Reply should be like this:**

```
Reply test 1


-----------------------------
The 2014-01-17 02:45:55, Mikey said : Test 1
```

Edit:  When the reply  button is pushed, Jquery is adding  something inside the contianr as follows `$('#mess_texarea').text('\n\n\n' + '----------------------------- The '+ date + ', ' +remit + '  said :' + '\n'  + text);`

Comment: How do you convert code before inserting it into DB? Show your code part, please.

Comment: Im not conveting the POST yet, as I get the POST, im inserting into the DB `$query =  "INSERT INTO mail(remi,idremi,dest,iddest,messa) VALUES ('{$_POST['remit']}',{$_POST['idremit']},'{$_POST['for']}',{$_POST['idfor']},'{$_POST['message']}')";`

Answer (score 0):

When you echo message body use `nl2br` as the message is most probably sent as HTML and HTML removes white spaces so you need to convert your new lines to `<br>` tags to show as new lines

Comment: When the reply is sent im just taking the $_POST['message'] and inserting on to the DB